# Shut down Windows programmatically and wait for termination of resident processes

Tags: windows, system-shutdown

### Background

- I am writing a program to shut down Windows at the specified time. I am using `shutdown.exe` to implement this function.
- In my computer, there is a resident process to record system activity and send the record to a server when shutting down Windows. When you shut down Windows from the start menu (`RuntimeBroker.exe`), Windows waits for the resident process to finish sending the record (according to `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\HungAppTimeout`).

### Problem

When I shut down Windows with `shutdown.exe`, it doesn't refer to `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\HungAppTimeout` and kills the resident process forcibly before it finishes sending the record.

### Question

Is there any way (like a PowerShell cmdlet or a command included in Windows) to shut down Windows programmatically and wait for the termination of the resident processes gracefully before the shutdown?

Comment: Did you already try "Stop-Compuer" in PowerShell? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @An-dir's advice, I have tested some ways to shutdown Windows:

| # | How to shutdown | What is executed | Wait for HungAppTimeout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shutdown from Start Menu | `RuntimeBroker.exe` | Yes |
| 2 | run `shutdown.exe` | `shutdown.exe` | No |
| 3 | run `SlideToShutDown.exe` | `SlideToShutDown.exe` | Yes |
| 4 | run `Stop-Computer` cmdlet | `WmiPrvSE.exe` | Yes |
| 5 | shut down from the lock screen | `winlogon.exe` | No |
| 6 | Alt+F4 on Desktop | `Explorer.exe` | Yes |

For my purpose, `Stop-Computer` and `SlideToShutDown.exe` look suitable.